# Show any Month/Year Javascript Calendar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to code a calendar using HTML and JavaScript that allows the user to choose any month in a given year to look at.  I set up an HMTL form that has a drop down list to choose the month and an input box to enter the desired year.  There are also buttons coded to toggle between the month and year, along with showing the current month.  All of that is working, and I was able to get the calendar to show up as well for the current month.

What I am struggling with is getting the calendar display to change when I hit the toggle buttons or when I choose a desired month/year and hit the display button.  I'm not sure what to do to get my calendar to work the way it is supposed to.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src = "CalendarFunction.js"></script>
    <link href="Calendartest.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body onLoad = "CreateCalendar()">
    <form name = "DateControl" id = "DateControl" onSubmit = "return false;" method = "post">
      <!--Select the month and year to be shown -->
      <select name = "Month" id = "month" onChange = "ChooseDate()">
        <option value="January" id="January">January</option>
        <option value="February" id="February">February</option>
        <option value="March" id="March">March</option>
        <option value="April" id="April">April</option>
        <option value="May" id="May">May</option>
        <option value="June" id="June">June</option>
        <option value="July" id="July" >July</option>
        <option value="August" id="August">August</option>
        <option value="September" id="September">September</option>
        <option value="October" id="October" >October</option>
        <option value="November" id="November">November</option>
        <option value="December" id="December">December</option>
      </select>
      <input name = "Year" type = "text" maxlength = "4">
      <!-- Show Calendar -->
      <input type = "button" name = "create" value = "Show" onClick = "ChooseDate()">
      </TD>
      </TR>
      <!--Toggle between the months of the year -->
      <input type = "button" name = "previousYear" value = "<Year" onClick = "PreviousYear()">
      <input type = "button" name = "previousMonth" value = "<Month" onClick = "PreviousMonth()">
      <input type = "button" name = "current" value = "Current" onClick = "SetDate()">
      <input type = "button" name = "nextYear" value = ">Year" onClick = "NextYear()">
      <input type = "button" name = "nextMonth" value = ">Month"onClick = "NextMonth()" >
    </form>
    <div id = "calendar"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function SetDate() {
    var now = new Date();
    var day = now.getDate();
    var month = now.getMonth();
    var year = now.getFullYear();
    this.focusDay = day;
    document.DateControl.Month.selectedIndex = month;
    document.DateControl.Year.value = year;
    displayCalendar(month, year);
}

function isFourDigitYear(year) {
    if (year.length != 4) {
        alert("Sorry, the year must be four-digits in length.");
        document.DateControl.Year.select();
        document.DateControl.Year.focus();
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function ChooseDate() {
    var year = document.DateControl.Year.value;
    if (isFourDigitYear(year)) {
        var day = 0;
        var month = document.DateControl.Month.selectedIndex;
        displayCalendar(month, year);
    }
}

function PreviousYear() {
    var year = document.DateControl.Year.value;
    if (isFourDigitYear(year)) {
        var day = 0;
        var month = document.DateControl.Month.selectedIndex;
        year--;
        document.DateControl.Year.value = year;
        displayCalendar(month, year);
    }
}

function PreviousMonth() {
    var year = document.DateControl.Year.value;
    if (isFourDigitYear(year)) {
        var day = 0;
        var month = document.DateControl.Month.selectedIndex;
        if (month == 0) {
            month = 11;
            if (year > 1000) {
                year--;
                document.DateControl.Year.value = year;
            }
        } else {
            month--;
        }
        document.DateControl.Month.selectedIndex = month;
        displayCalendar(month, year);
    }
}

function NextMonth() {
    var year = document.DateControl.Year.value;
    if (isFourDigitYear(year)) {
        var day = 0;
        var month = document.DateControl.Month.selectedIndex;
        if (month == 11) {
            month = 0;
            year++;
            document.DateControl.Year.value = year;
        } else {
            month++;
        }
        document.DateControl.Month.selectedIndex = month;
        displayCalendar(month, year);
    }
}

function NextYear() {
    var year = document.DateControl.Year.value;
    if (isFourDigitYear(year)) {
        var day = 0;
        var month = document.DateControl.Month.selectedIndex;
        year++;
        document.DateControl.Year.value = year;
        displayCalendar(month, year);
    }
}

function CreateCalendar() {
    var htmlContent = "";
    var FebNumberOfDays = "";
    var counter = 1;
    var now = new Date();
    var day = now.getDate();
    var month = now.getMonth();
    var year = now.getFullYear();
    var nextMonth = month + 1;
    var prevMonth = month - 1;

    if (month == 1) {
        if ((year % 100 != 0) && (year % 4 == 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
            FebNumberOfDays = 29;
        } else {
            FebNumberOfDays = 28;
        }
    }

    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    var dayPerMonth = ["31", "" + FebNumberOfDays + "", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31"];

    var nextDate = new Date(nextMonth + ' 1 ,' + year);
    var weekdays = nextDate.getDay();
    var weekdays2 = weekdays;
    var numOfDays = dayPerMonth[month];

    while (weekdays > 0) {
        htmlContent += "<td class='monthPre'></td>";
        weekdays--;
    }

    while (counter <= numOfDays) {

        if (weekdays2 > 6) {
            weekdays2 = 0;
            htmlContent += "</tr><tr>";
        }

        if (counter == day) {
            htmlContent += "<td class='dayNow'>" + counter + "</td>";
        } else {
            htmlContent += "<td class='monthNow'>" + counter + "</td>";
        }

        weekdays2++;
        counter++;
    }

    var calendarBody = "<table class='calendar'> <tr class='monthNow'><th colspan='7'>" +
        monthNames[month] + " " + year + "</th></tr>";

    calendarBody += "<tr class='dayNames'>  <td>Sun</td>  <td>Mon</td> <td>Tues</td>" +
        "<td>Wed</td> <td>Thurs</td> <td>Fri</td> <td>Sat</td> </tr>";
    calendarBody += "<tr>";
    calendarBody += htmlContent;
    calendarBody += "</tr></table>";
    document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML = calendarBody;
}
```

CSS

```
.monthPre{
    color: gray;
    text-align: center;
}
.monthNow{
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
.dayNow{
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: #FF0;
    text-align: center;
}
.calendar td{
    htmlContent: 2px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
}
.monthNow th{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;

}
.dayNames{
    background: #0FF000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Your ChooseDate() is calling displayCalendar(month, year); which doesn't exist.

Comment: As @jeff said your displayCalendar funciton is missing, you can probably easily change your createCalendar function to also function as a displayCalendar function, accepting the month, year arguments and using them instead of now.

Comment: I addressed the displayCalendar function issue that you guys pointed out and made that the name of the "CreateCalendar" function and made the parameters of it month and year.  I then kept that function call inside of my other functions that toggle between the months and years.  That didn't do the trick as the calendar display still doesn't change when I click the buttons.  I have spent the last 2 weeks trying to figure out the issue but can't seem to figure this one out.  I am out of ideas of what to try.

Comment: I have to create this calendar for a client website and it is supposed to be an events calendar.  The idea is that the events will be entered by the organization where the events will automatically be updated on the calendar dynamically.  I do not know where to start when it comes to coding this.  I know I have to use an API, but this is something I haven't done before.  Please help!